# Pass list from model class to DbInitliazer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to C#. I'm working on a web app project. I want to know how to initialize the list in my DbInitializer class. For example, this is the Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Manager.Model
{

    public class Vendor
    {
        public int VendorID { get; set; }
        public string CardName { get; set; }
        public string WebsiteLink { get; set; }
        public DateTime PartnerSince { get; set; }
        public List<Rep> Reps { get; set; }
        public string SupportNo { get; set; }
        public string SupportEmail { get; set; }
        public string Rebate { get; set; }
        public string Spiff { get; set; }
        public string Quote { get; set; }
    }
    public class Rep
    {
        public string RepName { get; set; }
        public string RepPosition { get; set; }
        public string RepNo { get; set; }
        public string RepEmail { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How would I pass this list in the Initialize method?

```
public static void Initialize(ManagementContext context)
    {
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        // Look for any students.
        if (context.Vendors.Any())
        {
            return;   // DB has been seeded
        }


        var vendors = new Vendor[]
        {
        new Vendor{CardName="Vendor1", WebsiteLink="www.vendor1.com", PartnerSince=DateTime.Parse("10-10-2012"), SupportNo="521-586-8956", SupportEmail="nikki@vendor1.com"},          
        };

        foreach (Vendor v in vendors)
        {
            context.Vendors.Add(v);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I did not get the DBIntializer part, but if you want to pass the list, user `List<Vendor> list = new List<Vendor>` and to add items like `list.Add(new Vendor(){prop1 = '' ... });`

Comment: I want to past the public List<Rep> Reps (which includes all info of representatives to contact) onto the Vendor object. I just updated the post with the entire DbInitializer code.

Comment: In other words, how do I pass the list items to this line: new Vendor {CardName=......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to do everything inline:

```
 Vendor[] vendors = new Vendor[]
 {
    new Vendor() // first vendor
    {
       CardName="Vendor1",
       WebsiteLink="www.vendor1.com",
       PartnerSince=DateTime.Parse("10-10-2012"), 
       SupportNo="521-586-8956",
       SupportEmail="nikki@vendor1.com",
       Reps = new List<Rep>()
       {
           new Rep() // first rep
           {
              RepName = "name",
              RepPosition = "pos",
              RepNo = "no",
              RepEmail = "email"
           }
           // , new Rep(){...}  // second rep, etc...
       }
    }
    // , new Vendor(){....}    // second vendor, etc...    
 };
```

---

Or simply prepare the Reps first:

```
List<Rep> Reps1 = new List<Rep>(); // Reps 1 for Vendor 1
Reps1.Add(new Rep()
{
     RepName = "name",
     RepPosition = "pos",
     RepNo = "no",
     RepEmail = "email"
});
// you may add more rep
```

then assign it in vendor

```
Vendor[] vendors = new Vendor[]
{
    new Vendor() // first vendor
    {
        CardName="Vendor1",
        WebsiteLink="www.vendor1.com",
        PartnerSince=DateTime.Parse("10-10-2012"), 
        SupportNo="521-586-8956",
        SupportEmail="nikki@vendor1.com",
        Reps = Reps1
     }
     // , new Vendor(){....}    // second vendor, etc...    
};
```

---

For question if you change into string[] RepNames,

```
string[] RepNames1 = new string[]
{
     "name1",
     "name2" // , etc....
}
```

then assign it in vendor

```
Vendor[] vendors = new Vendor[]
{
    new Vendor() // first vendor
    {
        CardName="Vendor1",
        WebsiteLink="www.vendor1.com",
        PartnerSince=DateTime.Parse("10-10-2012"), 
        SupportNo="521-586-8956",
        SupportEmail="nikki@vendor1.com",
        RepNames = RepNames1
     }
     // , new Vendor(){....}    // second vendor, etc...    
};
```

Comment: If I want to change it to array instead (I would use public string[] RepNames in the model), how do I pass it in the Vendor object?

Comment: Last question: for the List items, how do I display them individually? For example, I want to display Rep1's RepName.